# Проблема с дженериками в java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы выполнялось арифметическое действие, и, в зависимости от того, какое число должно выводиться на экран, метод возвращал или int или double.

реализую это так:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface JoinMathAction<T extends Number>
{
    T mathAction(Number a, Number b);
}


public class GoMath
{
    public <T extends  Number> T getResultMath(T arg1, T arg2, String op)
    {
        Number res = 0;

        if (arg1 instanceof Integer && arg2 instanceof Integer) {
            JoinMathAction<Integer> mm = (a, b) ->
            {
                int argFirst = a.intValue(), argSec = b.intValue();
                switch (op) {
                    case "/": {
                        if(argFirst == 0 || argSec == 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                throw new DivZeroException("Ділення на 0 неможливе");
                            }
                            catch (DivZeroException d)
                            {
                                System.out.println(d.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return argFirst / argSec;
                        }
                    }
                    case "*": {
                        return argFirst * argSec;

                    }
                    case "-": {
                        return argFirst - argSec;
                    }
                    case "+": {
                        return argFirst + argSec;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            };

            res = mm.mathAction(arg1, arg2);

        } else if (arg1 instanceof Double || arg2 instanceof Double) {
            JoinMathAction<Double> mm = (a, b) ->
            {
                double argFirst = a.doubleValue(), argSec = b.doubleValue();
                double result = 0;

                switch (op) {
                    case "/": {
                        if(argFirst == 0 || argSec == 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                throw new DivZeroException("Ділення на 0 неможливе");
                            }
                            catch (DivZeroException d)
                            {
                                System.out.println(d.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return argFirst / argSec;
                        }
                    }
                    case "*": {
                        return argFirst * argSec;
                    }
                    case "-": {
                        return argFirst - argSec;
                    }
                    case "+": {
                        return argFirst + argSec;
                    }
                }
                return result;
            };

            res = mm.mathAction(arg1, arg2);
        }
        return (T) res;
    }
}
```

Все работает, но как сделать с двух switch один? И как это сделать грамотно?

Comment: А почему вы не разрешаете нулевой _числитель_?

Comment: @VladD, при делении на 0 у меня выбрасывает Exception.

Comment: @Vitaliy, числитель - это число, _которое_ делят. А зачем `try(){...}catch(){...}` если можно сразу вывести сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что не так с генериками уже объяснили. Я же представлю вариант выхода из безвыходной ситуации с одним switch-ом.
Сделайте из Number BigDecimal. У него есть методы, реализующие арифметические операции. Складывайте, вычитайте, умножайте и делите BigDecimal в одном switch-е, а результат переведите обратно в int или double:

```
public <T extends  Number> T getResultMath(T arg1, T arg2, String op) {
    BigDecimal bigArg1 = new BigDecimal(arg1 instanceof Integer ? arg1.intValue() : arg1.doubleValue());
    // или в любом случае используя doubleValue
    BigDecimal bigArg2 = new BigDecimal(arg2.doubleValue());
    BigDecimal bigResult;
    switch (op) {
       ...
       case "*" :
           bigResult = bigArg1.multiply(bigArg2);
           break;
       ...
    }
    // Округления при переводе в int сами найдёте как сделать
    return (T) (arg1 instanceof Integer ? new Integer(bigResult.intValue()) : new Double(bigResult.doubleValue()));
}
```

Вообще-то не обязательно использовать `BigDecimal`. Можно тот же `double` с успехом применить.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще это проблема не про `Generic`, а про `autoboxing`. У классов `Integer` и `Double` тоже не определено ни одной арифметической операции и если вы попробуете скомпилировать код вида:

```
void add(Integer b, Integer c){
    Integer a = b + c;
}
```

В Java 1.4, то у вас ничего не получится, такой код начинает работать только с версии 1.5, когда собственно и появился `autoboxing`. И в Java 1.5 в байт коде будет:

```
void add(Integer b, Integer c) {
   Integer a = Integer.valueOf(b.intValue() + c.intValue());
}
```

А т.к. для класса `Number` нельзя заранее определить как его преобразовать, то и арифметическую операцию применить нельзя.

Comment: Это на самом деле следствие слабости системы типов Java. (У .NET та же проблема, по сути, но можно воспользоваться `dynamic`.)

Comment: @VladD С# стал динамически типизируемым? можно тогда уж и про Groovy вспомнить, который на JVM работает, там тоже таких проблем нет.

Comment: Давно уже :) В смысле, динамическая часть — только с `dynamic`, остальное такое же, как было.